# Can Node.js launch scripts on the server?

Tags: node.js

Can Node.js launch scripts on the server it is installed on? Scripts like bash scripts or PHP scripts, for example to resize pictures?

If so, how how is it? Can you point me to a documentation page, please?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The following give a demonstration:

1. http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs
2. http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/e3d00bb0e48dd760?pli=1

You can also perform tasks such as spawning child processes, and clustering.

Executing a unix command:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
child = exec("something", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
  sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
  if (error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
});
```

**See Node.js Documentation for more:** http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Wonderful answer, I would suggest using child_process.execFile(file, args, options, callback) instead of exec. execFile is more specific and better for the scenario you mentioned in your question. http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback